# Proof that serie is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I proof that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{3}-1$$ diverges? Which criterium should I use?
I have tried integral criterium, but it was difficult to calculate. Maybe comparison test would be great, bu I have no idea with which serie should I compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for all $a>-1$ we have by using Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
\exp(a) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{a}{m}\right)^m \geq \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (1+a) = 1+a
$$
Plugging in $c = \frac{1}{n}$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ yields
$$
\underbrace{\exp\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)}_{=\sqrt[n]{e}} \geq1+\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{3} - 1 \geq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{e} - 1 \geq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1+ \frac{1}{n}-1 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty.
$$

So divergence by the comparison test.

Comment: I understand, thank you.